# PHP url into html img src

Tags: php, html

i'm using and url from Facebook to insert into HTML img src .. that url is not an image, this url (when opened on a browser) redirects to an image.

```
 <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/274084006029120/picture?width=100" />
```

This image is shown correctly everywhere.

Then I build a cover.php program that only redirect to an http://../image.jpg

Then i add on HTML source

```
 <img src="https://.../cover.php" />
```

On most browsers and emails this cover.php program Works fine and shows the picture. But on some components (editors) seems the php is not executed and the picture is not show.

How can i solve this ? or how can i do redirect (need some code before) to work like Facebook redirect ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: php is run server side, so the client is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redirect browser with adding this line to your php code:

```
header('Location: http://..../image_url');
```

Comment: yes now it's working and redirecting perfect. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can get the redirected url like in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26205505/1880431)

```
$url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/274084006029120/picture?width=100';

file_get_contents($url);
preg_match('/(Location:|URI:)(.*?)\n/', implode("\n", $http_response_header), $matches);

if (isset($matches[0]))
{
    echo "<img src='".matches[0]."' />";
}
```